# Loop for copy-pasting values based on names in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataset "datP" that I am trying to add a new variable named "threshold" to. The values I need to add are stored in a test dataframe that looks like this (country codes as rownames and income as the sole variable).  I calculated those income values for each country in my main dataset ("DatP") and saved the resulting vector as a "test" dataframe with 32 observations for one variable.

```
AT   42617.1
BE   43575.0
BG   35639.4
CH   63240.6
CY   28153.2
CZ   33948.6
```

The original dataset I want to add my new variable to has a country variable named PB020 that has the same country codes as the rownames in my test dataframe,

```
head(levels(datP$PB020))
[1] "AT" "BE" "BG" "CH" "CY" "CZ"
```

but way more observations for each country. Now, I could paste my results for each country code 32 times like so

```
datP$threshold[datP$PB020=="AT"]<-test$AT 
datP$threshold[datP$PB020=="BE"]<-test$BE
```

but obviously this is ridiculous. I cannot for the life of mine write a proper for loop, I have tried pretty much every version of it, read all the documentation and examples and to be honest, I don't understand it. Is there any way to easily and automatically do this? I tried searching for examples (and I am very very sorry, this question has probably been asked before), but I have no idea what the name is for what I am trying to do so I don't know how to search for it, and also none of the examples I've seen fit my case.

Many thanks!

Comment: This looks like a join / merge process. Have you tried those?

Answer (score 2):

```
# country dataset (might have other columns as well)
df1 = data.frame(PB020 = c("AT", "BE", "BG", "CH", "BE", "BG", "CY", "CZ"))

df1

#   PB020
# 1    AT
# 2    BE
# 3    BG
# 4    CH
# 5    BE
# 6    BG
# 7    CY
# 8    CZ

# threshold dataset
df2 = read.table(text = "
                 thr
                 42617.1
                 43575.0
                 35639.4
                 63240.6
                 28153.2
                 33948.6
                 ", header=T)

row.names(df2) = c("AT", "BE", "BG", "CH", "CY", "CZ")

df2

#        thr
# AT 42617.1
# BE 43575.0
# BG 35639.4
# CH 63240.6
# CY 28153.2
# CZ 33948.6

# add row names as a variable
df2$Country = row.names(df2)

# merge them
merge(df1, df2, by.x="PB020", by.y="Country", all.x = T)

#   PB020     thr
# 1    AT 42617.1
# 2    BE 43575.0
# 3    BE 43575.0
# 4    BG 35639.4
# 5    BG 35639.4
# 6    CH 63240.6
# 7    CY 28153.2
# 8    CZ 33948.6
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that in my test dataframe, the country codes are rownames, not a variable in itself. I calculated those income values for each country in my main dataset ("DatP") and saved the resulting vector as a "test" dataframe that has 32 observatuions of only one variable (the income). That's why it's not merging I need (I think).

Comment: Solution updated. Row names will be added as a column/variable, before the join. That will hopefully solve your problem.